# Janela customizada diferente da padrao em python

Tags: python, tkinter

oi, gostaria de um exemplo de janela em Python, diferente da padrão, como eu faço isso ???

este é o meu codigo:

```
from tkinter import = 
root = Tk()
theLabel = Label(root, text="This is too easy")
theLabel.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tenho certeza se entendi o diferente, mas você pode mudar o tema das janelas para utilizar elementos nativos do sistema (X11, Windows, etc.) com o comando [from ttk import *](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ttk.html):

Exemplo:

Sem o `ttk`:

[image: Janela padrão]

Com o `ttk`:

[image: Janela nativa]

Exemplo gerado com:

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *  # basta acrescentar ou retirar esta linha
root = Tk()
Frame(root)
if (root is not None):
    root.title("Teste")
    theLabel = Label(root, text="This is too easy")
    theLabel.pack(fill='both')
    sair = Button(root, text="Sair", command=quit)
    sair["state"] = "normal"
    sair.pack(fill='both')
    root.mainloop()
```